# Output of the cout changes according to typecasting way

Tags: c++, hex, int, cout

I'm working on a program and have a strange, cout related problem. Since the program is a bit big and the code talks best, I'll paste the relevant snippets.

First, I have an iterator, `*it` defined in a for as

`for(vector<facet*>::iterator it=facets_to_dump->begin(); it<facets_to_dump->end(); it++)`

In this for, if I use the expression

```
facet* facet_to_work_on = *it;
cout << facet_to_work_on->facet_id << "\t";
```

Nicely prints out integers.

But, if I use the notation

```
cout << (facet*)(*it)->facet_id << "\t";
```

This code prints out hex values. Hex values are equal to the integer values. Any idea why this is happening?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason

```
cout << (facet*)(*it)->facet_id << "\t";
```

prints out a hex value is that -> binds harder than the (facet*) cast, that is it evaluates

```
(*it)->facet_id
```

and casts the result to a facet*. Pointers are output in hex.

Answer (score -1):

Try including `<iomanip>` and:

```
 cout << dec << (facet*)(*it)->facet_id << "\t";
```

To say you want numbers in decimal form.

Comment: Unfortunately, the output is still hex.